# JMeter zip file download from server

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a requirement to download zip file from server through JMeter to test the peroformance but for me the downloaded files are shown in x-filler, i need to have the zip file downladed.

Please help me here

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Simulating file download event using JMeter is as simple as sending [HTTP GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request using [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler.

If you need to save the response somewhere for later reuse or analysis add [Save Response to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener as a child of the request which performs the download. Check out [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article for comprehensive explanation.

---

Be aware that storing responses will cause huge disk IO overhead during the load test so I would recommend ticking `Save response as MD5 hash` box under "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler and use [MD5Hex Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MD5Hex_Assertion) to compare the [MD5 checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) of the response with some reference value.

Answer (score -1):

To download any file, you need to extract it using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor).

Add the **Regular Express Extractor** to the request where you want to download and configure the fields as shown below. Use **(?s)(^.*)** as the expression to extract everything.

[image]

Add the **Save Responses to a File** sampler and configure the fields as shown below.

[image]

Execute the test plan. In the **JMETER_HOME\bin\,** you can see the zip file. Extract the zip file and validate.

Comment: Jmeter saves the file as ${myzipfile} and not replacing the variable name instead.

Comment: Please share your test plan.

Comment: Will upload in a week. On to other projects. Will get back to this in about a week.

Comment: After having some issues with this, seems like `Save Responses to a File` listener is not synchronous. so if you are planning on performing an immediate action on the file saved by that element, **BEWARE:** it might not exist yet/not fully created. Also, thanks for the tip @NaveenKumarNamachivayam

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to use your own code to download the file. The options are BeanShell Postprocessor or JSR223 Postprocesor.

I extracted file name from response header Content-Disposition, save it to varible, and the use variable for filename. Additional variable was defined on Test level, holding folder name where to save files.

[image: Get the file name from headers]

[image: Save to disc]